# How to prove that in the unit circle the tangent line in a given point is equal to slope of the radius that intersects the circle in that same point?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I know that we can get the length of the tangent line of the unit circle by finding the slope of the radius that will intersect the circle in the point of tangency, I have tried it and it checks out but I'm having a hard time coming up with the intuition that leads to this. I can see that as the slope of the radius grows it tends to the vertical slope that will never be and the tangent line tends to the horizontal line that will never be defined in a direct relation but this fails to completely satisfy me. I Can anyone help me think about this?

Comment: The line you mean is called a “secant’ line. Radii end at the circle.

Comment: There’s not much to prove here, I don’t think. Slope = rise / run, no? The run is constant—equal to the radius of the circle—while the rise is the length of the tangent segment at the point that it intersects the secant line. To relate that to sine over cosine, use similar triangles.

Answer (score 0):

By a well-known theorem from geometry, the tangent to a circle $C$ at a point $P$ is perpendicular to the radius $\overline{CP}$ of the circle, meaning that if the slope of the radius at that point is $m$, then the slope of the tangent is $-\frac{1}{m}$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

use fact that radius line $OM $ is perpendicular to the tangent line at the point $M $.